# Graphics/vnc/ssh connect failed failed

Tags: root-access, linux, android-emulator, selinux, vnc

Installed Kali Linux rolling through deploy on coolpad cool1. Debugging mode on. Rooted. Busbox checked. And terminal also fails to start. More info and config in the screenshots given below
[image: graphics:VNC failed]
[image: vnc 1]
[image: vnc 2]
[image: config 1]
[image: config 2]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Cannot connect through vnc

Comment: You installed Kali on phablet??? Wow. So you can easily check `lsof -i` and see if your ports are listened

Comment: No sir. Its not a phablet. Its a smartphone. Coolpad cool 1 dual. I didn't download the kali through Linux deploys native links. I downloaded the image externally but that shouldn't be a problem. I tried so many solutions none of them seems to work. Vnc says the port refused to connect. i could provide u with more details and logs if needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I downloaded the image externally` what means externally?

Comment: Either u let Linux deploy app download the kali image automatically or u give a path to the externally downloaded kali image file Which in my case is from  https://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxonandroid/files/Kali%20Linux/. Sir can u provide a solution. Why am i unable to install kali linux on my smartphone, which basically is easy to install on most of the very  basic android phone. My root problem is with connecting the gui with the help of vnc. And also the inbuilt terminal app doesn't start. Search "kali vnc fail" for more light on the context for there hasn't been any of a good solution